# Cannot find source of "class, interface, or enum expected" error

Tags: java, enums

While trying to build this project, I continue to receive an error `class, interface, or enum expected`. I have moved things about all over the place, but I can't seem to work out what's wrong. Can somebody help, please?

The error as displayed in the console is:

```
ant -f C:\\Users\\x\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\DisplayDataUsingJTable -Dnb.internal.action.name=rebuild clean jar
init:
deps-clean:
Updating property file: C:\Users\x\Documents\NetBeansProjects\DisplayDataUsingJTable\build\built-clean.properties
Deleting directory C:\Users\x\Documents\NetBeansProjects\DisplayDataUsingJTable\build
clean:
init:
deps-jar:
Created dir: C:\Users\x\Documents\NetBeansProjects\DisplayDataUsingJTable\build
Updating property file: C:\Users\x\Documents\NetBeansProjects\DisplayDataUsingJTable\build\built-jar.properties
Created dir: C:\Users\x\Documents\NetBeansProjects\DisplayDataUsingJTable\build\classes
Created dir: C:\Users\x\Documents\NetBeansProjects\DisplayDataUsingJTable\build\empty
Created dir: C:\Users\x\Documents\NetBeansProjects\DisplayDataUsingJTable\build\generated-sources\ap-source-output
Compiling 3 source files to C:\Users\x\Documents\NetBeansProjects\DisplayDataUsingJTable\build\classes
C:\Users\x\Documents\NetBeansProjects\DisplayDataUsingJTable\src\pack1\DisplayPerson.java:245: error: class, interface, or enum expected
    private void initComponents() {
C:\Users\x\Documents\NetBeansProjects\DisplayDataUsingJTable\src\pack1\DisplayPerson.java:248: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        setFocusable(false);
C:\Users\x\Documents\NetBeansProjects\DisplayDataUsingJTable\src\pack1\DisplayPerson.java:250: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
C:\Users\Imtiaaz\Documents\NetBeansProjects\DisplayDataUsingJTable\src\pack1\DisplayPerson.java:251: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
C:\Users\x\Documents\NetBeansProjects\DisplayDataUsingJTable\src\pack1\DisplayPerson.java:252: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
C:\Users\x\Documents\NetBeansProjects\DisplayDataUsingJTable\src\pack1\DisplayPerson.java:256: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
C:\Users\x\Documents\NetBeansProjects\DisplayDataUsingJTable\src\pack1\DisplayPerson.java:261: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        pack();
C:\Users\x\Documents\NetBeansProjects\DisplayDataUsingJTable\src\pack1\DisplayPerson.java:262: error: class, interface, or enum expected
    }// </editor-fold>//GEN-END:initComponents
8 errors
C:\Users\x\Documents\NetBeansProjects\DisplayDataUsingJTable\nbproject\build-impl.xml:924: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\x\Documents\NetBeansProjects\DisplayDataUsingJTable\nbproject\build-impl.xml:264: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

The error lines come here:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setFocusable(false);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
              .addGap(0, 1535, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
              .addGap(0, 755, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>
```

Full code below - excluding the sql statement:

```
/*
* To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
* To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/

package pack1;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;

public class DisplayPerson extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    String driverName = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
    String serverName = "xxxxx";
    String serverPort = "xxxx";
    String database = serverName + ":" + serverPort;
    String url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver:/" + database;
    String username = "xx";
    String password = "xxx";

    public DisplayPerson() throws SQLException {
        ArrayList columnNames = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList data = new ArrayList();

        try {
            Class.forName(driverName);
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);

            // Create and execute an SQL statement that returns some data.
            String SQL = "xxxxx";
            Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);
            ResultSetMetaData  rsmetadata = rs.getMetaData();

            int columns = rsmetadata.getColumnCount();

            //  Get column names
            for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
                columnNames.add( rsmetadata.getColumnName(i) );
            }

            //  Get row data
            while (rs.next()) {
                ArrayList row = new ArrayList(columns);

                for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
                    row.add( rs.getObject(i) );
                }

                data.add( row );
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DisplayPerson.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        // Create Vectors and copy over elements from ArrayLists to them
        // Vector is deprecated but I am using them in this example to keep 
        // things simple - the best practice would be to create a custom defined
        // class which inherits from the AbstractTableModel class
        Vector columnNamesVector = new Vector();
        Vector dataVector = new Vector();

        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
            ArrayList subArray = (ArrayList)data.get(i);
            Vector subVector = new Vector();
            for (int j = 0; j < subArray.size(); j++) {
                subVector.add(subArray.get(j));
            }
            dataVector.add(subVector);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < columnNames.size(); i++)
            columnNamesVector.add(columnNames.get(i));

        //  Create table with database data    
        JTable table;
        table = new JTable(dataVector, columnNamesVector) {

            public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
                for (int row = 0; row < getRowCount(); row++) {
                    Object o = getValueAt(row, column);

                    if (o != null) {
                        return o.getClass();
                    }
                }

                return Object.class;
            }
        };

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
        getContentPane().add( scrollPane );

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        getContentPane().add( buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH );
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws SQLException {
        DisplayPerson frame = new DisplayPerson();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setFocusable(false);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
              .addGap(0, 1535, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
              .addGap(0, 755, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

/**
* @param args the command line arguments
*/

    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
    * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
    */

    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    //java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

// Variables declaration - do not modify
// End of variables declaration
```

Comment: if could be a "copy code to stack overflow bug" but the second closing curly brace after your main() method should be below the curly brace after the pack(); method call.. look into Eclipse, it helps you out with curly braces, ( if that is indeed your issue..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure if you observed it or not, but your initComponents() method is outside the closing brace of the class DisplayPerson. Move it to inside the class and that particular error goes away

Comment: Many thanks, i couldnt see the wood through the trees with so many brackets, solved!!

Comment: I have no idea, because my english is not very good i keep getting moderators modyfing my original post. I dont know if its the moderators that downvote my post. But this is definetly solved

Answer (score 0):

I had the same sort of problem with Netbeans, turns out an errant closing '}' got in the middle of the main class. Found it by highliting the opening '{' at the class declaration and scrolling down to find the matching '}' that didn't belong.